# How to add Newtonsoft 9.0.1 in a .NET 4.6.1 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json.net

I'm unable to install `Newtonsoft 9.0.1` package in a 4.6.1 project via `nuget`. In .NET Core projects it seems to be OK.

Error message:

[image]

```
    PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -verbose

    GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Newtonsoft.Json'
    OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Newtonsoft.Json' 179ms

    Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' with respect to project 'ClassLibrary1', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
    Package Newtonsoft.Json from source nuget.org gathered from cache.
    Total number of results gathered : 2
    Gathering dependency information took 1,32 ms
    Summary of time taken to gather dependencies per source :
    Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
    Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
    Resolving actions to install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1'
    Resolved actions to install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1'
    Retrieving package 'Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1' from 'nuget.org'.
    For adding package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' to project 'ClassLibrary1' that targets 'net461'.
    For adding package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' to project 'ClassLibrary1' that targets 'net461'.
    Adding package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages'
    Added package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages'
    Install failed. Rolling back...
    Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' does not exist in project 'ClassLibrary1'
    Removing package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' from folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages'
    Removed folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81'.
    Removed folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81'.
    Removed folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\netstandard1.0'.
    Removed folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net20'.
    Removed folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net35'.
    Removed folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net40'.
    Removed folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net45'.
    Removed folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\tools'.
    Removed folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib'.
    Removed file 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1.nupkg' from folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1'.
    Removed folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1'.
    Removed package 'Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1' from folder 'C:\Users\robson.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages'
    Executing nuget actions took 548,1 ms
    Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -verbose
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

    Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.6617616
```

Is it a bug in the `Newtonsoft` version?

Comment: Please post error messages as text instead of images. It makes it better to read and easier to find by someone else later (e.g. via Google)

Comment: Just tried it, works fine for me... https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/283f7678b1ee1f47796a92deea0ceb98

Comment: What command did you use? Install-Package Newtonsoft -Version 9.0.1 ??

Comment: @RicardoFrança, I've tried via nuget manager but with command the error is the same.

Comment: You can set the output level to verbose which allows you to see more detailed information. If you want to try a quick fix, you might want to try Install-Package Newtonsoft -Version 9.0.1 -reinstall. This is very unlikely a bug in Newtonsoft or Visual Studio.

Comment: @hbulens, I've update the question with the output using verbose. Sadly the details didn't helped me to find the problem.

Comment: @rsilva Did you read this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653137/failed-to-add-reference-to-newtonsoft-json

Comment: For anyone visiting here, this version of newtonsoft 9.0.1 has a vulnerability https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5crp-9r3c-p9vr and should no longer be used. Update to 13.0.1.