# Unable to add any nuget package in vs 2017

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, .net-framework-version, visual-studio-2017

Am trying to add nuget package prism.core in vs 2017 and target framework is 4.6.1,its giving this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation'.
>   Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)

tried to install newtonsoft.json package, got this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Failed to add reference to 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
>   Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))          0

Not able to install any nuget package? is this is something to do with vs 2017?

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: No. Installing NuGet packages with VS2017 works just fine.

Comment: do you know why this message is coming "Library not registered", it used work fine before, now seeing all these errors.

Comment: @TomTom its not debugging help, this is first time am seeing this behavior while installing nuget packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to add reference to 'Newtonsoft.Json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653137/failed-to-add-reference-to-newtonsoft-json)

Comment: @BabakNaffas its not duplicate, facing this issue for every package, that talks about newtonsoft.json pacakge

Comment: These types of errors usually indicate a need to repair or reinstall VS2017.  They are too deep into the stack to make any sense to us "dumb" users.  Let me know if a simple repair or reinstall doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnPeters after repairing the visual studio, it worked

Comment: Seems to happen when you have too many VS editions installed at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> After repairing the visual studio, it worked.